# Is there a way to change the backround color of the native video player in wordpress?

Tags: css

I love the ease of adding a video to WordPress 3.9.1, however The background that shows befor the video fully loadsw is black and I would like it white. 
what is the name of the video player and where would I alter the styling to do this please, many thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the video embed shortcode?

If so add this to your theme or even better, child-theme style.css file:

```
.mejs-container, .mejs-embed, .mejs-embed body { background: #FFFFFF !important;}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for taking the time to answer, I see your in RSA, I used to work for PicknPay back in the 90's. Anyway, I am not using any shortcodes, just paste the link straight into the widget area. The website is http://websites4trades.co.uk/marks/. Any input very much appreciated. Regards and respect. Mark